# i have this error what is the solve for it

Tags: python

I have error I want **help** for it *please help me*

> **the error** ;

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/porgrammer/pythons/New folder/Main.py", line 6, in <module>
    yt = YouTube(url)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in get
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 564, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 756, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
PS C:\porgrammer\pythons\New folder> & C:/Users/belba/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe "c:/porgrammer/pythons/New folder/Main.py"
Enter The Link Of The Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoHpvfgj3WA
The Link Is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoHpvfgj3WA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1392, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/porgrammer/pythons/New folder/Main.py", line 6, in <module>
    yt = YouTube(url)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 162, in prefetch
    self.watch_html = request.get(url=self.watch_url)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in get
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

> **The Code** ;

```py
from pytube import YouTube

url = input("Enter The Link Of The Video: ")
print("The Link Is : " + url)
print("Copyright Srj")


yt = YouTube(url)

title =  yt.title * 60 
print("The Title Of The Video Is : " + title )

print("The Views Of The Video Is :" + yt.views)

print("The Lenght Of The Video Is : " + yt.length)

print("The Channel Who Post The Video Is : " + yt.rating)

print("The Description Of The Video Is : " + yt.description)

print("Copyright Srj")


YN = input("Are You Sure You Want To Install The Video?")

if YN == "yes" :
    ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    print("Downloading.......")
    ys.download("C:\YT_DOWNLOADS")
    print("Downlaod Completed!!")
    print("Copyright Srj")


elif YN == "no" :
    print("No Proplem")
    print("Copyright Srj")


else :
    print("Please Retry Again Because It Is Not yes Or no")
    print("Copyright Srj")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The hostname doesn’t resolve.

Comment: I posted an answer, go check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified some things in the code but never got the saame error as you.
This code works for me and even with the exact link of your video :

```
from pytube import YouTube

url = input("Enter The Link Of The Video: ")
print("The Link Is : " + url)
print("Copyright Srj")


yt = YouTube(url)

title =  yt.title
print("The Title Of The Video Is : " + title )

print(f"The Views Of The Video Is : {yt.views}")

print(f"The Lenght Of The Video Is : {yt.length}")

print(f"The Channel Who Post The Video Is : {yt.rating}")

print("The Description Of The Video Is : " + yt.description)

print("Copyright Srj")



while True:
    YN = str(input("Are You Sure You Want To Install The Video ? (yes / no)\n"))

    if YN.lower() == "yes" :
        ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        print("Downloading.......")
        ys.download("C:\YT_DOWNLOADS")
        print("Downlaod Completed!!")
        print("Copyright Srj")
        break


    elif YN.lower() == "no" :
        print("No Proplem")
        print("Copyright Srj")
        break


    else :
        print("Please Retry Again Because It Is Not yes Or no")
        print("Copyright Srj")
```

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: thx I found the problem i were having 3 version of python :) and I hope you liked the code.